# Как создать такое-же окно в приложении iOs? похоже на UIAlertController/UIAlertSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

[image]

И список вопросов:

1. Что это за класс? UIAlertView, UIAlertController, UIActionSheet?
2. Поле для ввода информации это кнопка или ячейка?
3. Как лучше
   организовать ввод информации в поле с телефоном?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Скорее всего кастомный класс. Такой не сложно написать, или даже найти на github.
2. Скорее всего UITextField.
3. Как я уже написал, это скорее всего UITextField, если вам надо чтоб выглядено как на картинке (со скобками и подчеркиваниями на месте не введенных символов), то надо в  `UITextFieldDelegate` в методе `- textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` смотреть какой символ ввели и на какой позиции, и:

   - изменять соответствующее подчеркивание на введенный символ
   - если нажат бэкспейс заменять цмфру на подчеркивание
   - если курсор на последнем символе игнорировать ввод (чтоб нельзя было ввести больше 10 цифр)